# Python returned multiple JSONs as a string in PHP

Tags: python, php, json

I'm having a bit  of trouble creating a JSON array in python and returning it to PHP.

Right now I have a PHP page that calls a Python script like this:

```php
$output1 = shell_exec("cd .. && cd python/pyjira && pipenv run py PyJira/Jira.py");
var_dump($output1);
```

The python script creates some JSON prints

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    jira = Jira()
    data = {}
    fields = jira.get_fields()
    jql_issues = jira.get_jql_search_issues(jql_search="project = SWAT AND resolution = Unresolved ORDER BY priority DESC, updated DESC")
    for issue in jql_issues:
        data['key'] = issue.key
        data['assignee'] = issue.fields.assignee.display_name
        print(json.dumps(data))
        exit
```

The output from python

```sh
{"key": "SWAT-107", "assignee": "Unassigned"}
{"key": "SWAT-98", "assignee": "Unassigned"}
{"key": "SWAT-100", "assignee": "Unassigned"}
{"key": "SWAT-97", "assignee": "Unassigned"}
{"key": "SWAT-75", "assignee": "Unassigned"}
{"key": "SWAT-129", "assignee": "Unassigned"}
```

This is the `var_dump(...);`  from PHP, and here you can see it's multiple JSON's in a single string

```php
"{"key": "SWAT-107", "assignee": "Unassigned"} {"key": "SWAT-98", "assignee": "Unassigned"} {"key": "SWAT-100", "assignee": "Unassigned"} {"key": "SWAT-97", "assignee": "Unassigned"} {"key": "SWAT-75", "assignee": "Unassigned"} {"key": "SWAT-129", "assignee": "Unassigned"} "
```

Is there a way to have python returning the JSON object one by one, so I can loop though them in PHP, and just do `data['key']` etc.?

I know when I just have one of the JSON's from the outout like `{"key": "SWAT-107", "assignee": "Unassigned"}` the I just need  to `json_decode(...)_;` it in PHP.

**Update**

As the comment suggested, I now tried to return a array from python, and get this on the PHP site:

```php
"['{"key": "SWAT-106", "assignee": "Unassigned"}', '{"key": "SWAT-107", "assignee": "Unassigned"}', '{"key": "SWAT-98", "assignee": "Unassigned"}', '{"key": "SWAT-100", "assignee": "Unassigned"}', '{"key": "SWAT-97", "assignee": "Unassigned"}', '{"key": "SWAT-75", "assignee": "Unassigned"}', '{"key": "SWAT-129", "assignee": "Unassigned"}'] "
```

How can I make it into a array?

Comment: What would need to be done to return each JSON object separately? Right now it prints each one individually with a newline between each one. What more do you want?

Comment: Why don't you return a JSON array? `[{"key": "somevalue", "assignee": "othervalue"}, {"key": "value", "assignee": "anothervalue"}]`. Then you can `json_decode` it just fine.

Comment: @mark_b thanks for the suggestion, see the updated field, the format is an array now, but it's as a  string still, how can I go from string->array

Comment: don't post [pictures of output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), post as text please.

Comment: @berend it's changed now

Comment: Found a solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution was more simple than I thought
If we start with the python, this is where the issue is.
First (as suggested from the comment) I put all the  JSON data into a array, useing `json.dump()` but then outside the loop I print the array with `json.dump()`, this makes PHP, know that the printet variable is a JSON.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    jira = Jira()
    data = {}
    output = []
    fields = jira.get_fields()
    jql_issues = jira.get_jql_search_issues(jql_search="project = SWAT AND resolution = Unresolved ORDER BY priority DESC, updated DESC")
    for issue in jql_issues:
        data['key'] = issue.key
        data['assignee'] = issue.fields.assignee.display_name
        output.append(json.dumps(data))

    print(json.dumps(output))
    exit
```

Over in my PHP I simply call the python script and fetch the JSON, then decode it. Then I have the array, and to get the `key` and `assignee` I have to decode it, and set `assosiative = TRUE` to convert object to array.

```php
$output1 = shell_exec("cd .. && cd python/pyjira && pipenv run py PyJira/Jira.py");
// Display the list of all file
// and directory
$decoded_output = json_decode($output1);
for ($i=0; $i < count($decoded_output); $i++) {
    $jira_data = json_decode($decoded_output[$i], true); // 'true' to convert object to array
    echo $jira_data['key'] . " - " . $jira_data['assignee'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the string before the update you posted I came up with this kinda messy solution:

```php
$string = '{"test1": "1", "test2": "2"} {"test3": "3", "test4": "4"} {"test5": "5", "test6": "6"}';
$array = explode(" {", $string);
foreach ($array as $k => $v){
    if(substr($v, 0, 1) != "{"){
        $array[$k] = "{" . $v;
    }
}
$finalArray = [];
foreach($array as $v) {
    $finalArray[] = json_decode($v);
}
```

I did it on my test $string which is simillar to yours and it creates me an array of objects (the $finalArray).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I found a solution for my problem, by solving is over in the python code.